# How to use TOP() on string fields in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

Given that 'location' is a string field in an influxdb bucket called `places` that has data resembling the following:

```
time                | location
--------------------+----------
1477568542209000000 | London
1477568542409000000 | Essex
1477568542569000000 | London
1477568542589000000 | Sussex
1477568542600000000 | Sussex
1477568542940000000 | London
```

How can I aggregate those to get them ordered by most common - least common, with a count for each? I would expect to be returned something like:

```
location | count
---------+-------
London   | 3
Sussex   | 2
Essex    | 1
```

My first thought was to use `SELECT TOP(location, 10) FROM places`, but this doesn't work with strings on fields. Is there an alternative approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cant think of a good way to achieve this kind of result without modifying your schema. And even then, the answer isn't particularly great

If you modified your schema to be something like

```
places,location=London x=1i <timestamp>
```

then you could run the following queries

```
SELECT count(x) INTO places_count FROM places GROUP BY location
SELECT top("count",10), location FROM places_count
```

Alternatively, you could keep the schema that you have and introduce [Kapacitor](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.2/) into the mix.